# Returning original 404 response in Nginx when legacy server also has 404

Tags: nginx

I have this Nginx config mostly working the way I want, it:

1. tries to get a page from node,
2. if there's a 404, try to get page from legacy version of website on different host
3. if the legacy version of the website returns 404, show a 404 page from the new website (instead of the legacy site's 404 page).

Note: this is an `envsubst` template.

```
location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_read_timeout 60;
    proxy_next_upstream error timeout http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;
    proxy_buffers 16 64k;
    proxy_buffer_size 2k;
    proxy_temp_file_write_size 64k;
    proxy_pass http://nodejs;

    proxy_intercept_errors on;
    recursive_error_pages on;
    error_page 404 = @legacy;

    location /404 {
        # serve up /404 from the node server
        internal;
        proxy_intercept_errors off;
        recursive_error_pages off;
        proxy_pass http://nodejs;
    }
}

location @legacy {
    # when we can't find a page on the new server, try to find it on the 
    # old web server. If still not found, show new site's 404 page.
    # NOTE: unfortunately, this can result in a 2nd call to our node
    # servers, even though we already have the response from them.
    proxy_pass ${LEGACY_URL};
    proxy_redirect default;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

    proxy_intercept_errors on;
    recursive_error_pages on;
    error_page 404 = /404;
}
```

The problem is:

1. If there's a 404 on the legacy site, a 2nd request gets made to my node backend.
2. That 2nd request won't have the original path info, it'll have /404.

Any way to get Nginx to return the original node 404 response at this point instead?